# How to filter neo4j nodes by the properties and (optionally) IDs of connected nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is a `:ActivityRecord` node in neo4j DB, intended for holding audit records in the database. Trying to filter them by various optional parameters, including `:Application`  and `:Tenant` organization where activity was performed.

Cypher query

```
MATCH (ac:ActivityRecord)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(t:Tenant), 
 (ac:ActivityRecord)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(a:Application) 
WHERE ac.objectId=coalesce(null, ac.objectId) AND ac.type=coalesce(null, ac.type) 
 AND ID(t)=coalesce(null, ID(t)) AND ac.changes =~ ".*test.*" 
RETURN ac 
ORDER BY ac.timestamp
```

returns no records, whereas query with `OPTIONAL MATCH` does not filter them appropriately (returns all records of `:ActivityRecord` type). How to make this query work in case `ID(t)=null` or `ID(a)=null`?

**[UPDATE]**

Clarification: actually, I am calling the below query from the application with appropriate parameters inserted to their places

```
MATCH (ac:ActivityRecord)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(t:Tenant), 
(ac:ActivityRecord)-[:GENERATED_IN]->(a:Application) 
WHERE ac.objectId=coalesce({objectId}, ac.objectId) 
AND ac.type=coalesce({type}, ac.type) 
AND ID(t)=coalesce({tenantId}, ID(t))
AND ID(a)=coalesce({applicationId}, ID(a)) 
AND ac.changes =~ ".*test.*" 
RETURN ac 
ORDER BY ac.timestamp
```

Because the parameters are optional, I need to handle situation when they are not specified. So I decided to use  `ID(t)=coalesce({tenantId}, ID(t))` for this case, what will be equal to `ID(t)=ID(t)` in case the `tenantId` param is not specified (so we just don't filter by this parameter, what I was going to actually achieve). The first query I specified was just a degraded case of the above query.

So the goal is to compose the query which will filter nodes by their attributes and by IDs of connected nodes (only if params are not null in the query).

Comment: I'm rather confused here. All nodes in Neo4j have system-generated id properties, ID(whatever) should NEVER return null, unless the variable you're passing in is itself null instead of a node. Also, I don't think you're using COALESCE properly. Every single part of your WHERE clause is basically comparing the values of these properties to themselves, except for the ac.changes comparison.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Please see my updated question. Hope this makes sense to you.